# Spark - Kubernetes - Using EBS Volume as backup

Tags: performance, apache-spark, kubernetes

I am working on Spark applicaton which runs on Kubernetes cluster.
At a times, the large jobs runs out of memory(Executor memory), thus leading to OOM errors.

To prevent it, I would to allocate disk space(EBS Volume) as a back up so that if Executor runs out of memory, I would like the EBS volume(disk space) to act as a back up so that the additional data will spill on disk.

In this regard, I want to know what Spark Configs I need to set as part of Spark-Submit command? What are the options i have to fall back(Ephermal storage, Disk Space/EBS Volumne) and how to use(through spark configs?) these volumes as a fallback storage so that Spark job won't fail.

I have tried setting up below configs.

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.ephemeralStorageGB.request xxx 
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.ephemeralStorageGB.limit xxx 
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.ephemeralStorageGB.request xxx 
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.ephemeralStorageGB.limit xxx
```

`